Apache Echarts GPU memory consumption in Edge vs Chrome
I am using Apache ECharts (canvas renderer) to plot a basic line chart of 25 series of 100 datapoints each (so, 2500 total data points). In Edge, this runs up my GPU memory consumption by about 1GB with each chart, and it releases very slowly over many minutes. If a user clicks from chart to chart, with each subsequent chart painting (new data), it adds an additional 1G each time until it gets around 7-8GB and crashes the GPU with a 5-second black screen, followed by the disappearance of the chart and a user feeling of site failure. This black screen of death takes only about 5 or 6 chart renderings to reach, which does not seem reasonable. Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Here's Edge on the 5th chart rendering:

One more refresh and the GPU will crash, at least on my workstation.
Interestingly, running the same site in Chrome, the memory consumption is far less. No matter how many charts I render and no matter how quickly I do so one after the other, the GPU process stays well below 200M, and it seems to clear the memory after each chart so it doesn't aggregate. Here's the same charts, same data, same site in Chrome after the 6th rendering:

Why is Chrome so much less? Any ideas on how to tame Edge's GPU memory usage when using ECharts? Is there a way I can make it behave like Chrome?

You can try navigating to windows setting>System>Display>Graphics. Under "Custom options for apps", select msedge.exe in this path: "C:\Program Files (x86) \Microsoft\Edge\Application", then click "Options" and select "High performance".
In addition, you also can open this page edge://settings/system in Edge and check if Use graphics acceleration when available is enabled? If it's enabled, disable it.
Of course, it is best to change Edge Update to the latest version.

I can do that for my workstation, perhaps, but that isn't going to do anything for all my users' experience. I can't ask all my users to make such changes. Whatever solution there is has to be in my control as the website designer.

If your users belong to a domain, you can also disable the policy (HardwareAccelerationModeEnabled) in the domain controller. This way users within the domain don't have to make such changes. You can refer to this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#hardwareaccelerationmodeenabled

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that won't work with a large nationwide company where my app is only a tiny fraction of what goes on in IT. You can't disable an important feature that would impact a lot of apps just to facilitate one app. I must find a solution entirely in my control as the site programmer, which means it must be javascript or CSS based.

Maybe I can give you another idea. You can use the memory tool in the browser's developer tools to debug your code. You can refer to the related document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/memory-problems/

The memory tool only reports stack/heap. My Javascript memory isn't excessively large (a couple hundred MB at most). It's the GPU that hogs up multiple GB, and there is no way to investigate that using dev tools, as far as I know.

I understand what you mean. I searched for relevant resources. May I ask if you use the WebGPU API, which can better optimize graphics rendering performance and computing power in web browsers. If you don't use this API, you can refer to this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGPU_API

That's an idea; I use Apache ECharts, and it appears they support a couple of GL graph types, but all their examples are for highly complex animations. I'm not sure how much would be involved to try to learn it and discover whether it can handle your basic line chart. But I would think we want to avoid using the GPU, not intentionally use it, as my issue is excessive GPU memory usage, not performance. At this point I think I'm simply going to tell my users to use Chrome rather than Edge.

OK. The most direct measure for Edge related render graphics is to use Edge's basic settings. But if you want to use JS or CSS, I have not found more APIs to avoid Edge using the GPU when rendering graphics. I suggest that you can try to submit feedback in Edge (press "Shift+Alt+I") to report the problem of Edge GPU using too much memory.
